# Facebook Pixel Code works on Chrome but not on Safari or Firefox

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

I have Facebook pixel installed on a website. The initial implementation was the very straightforward addition of code the the website as provided by facebook.

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
   fbq('init', '<truncated-Pixel-ID>');
   fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

But later I wanted to add additional features like using Multiple Pixels - one for Stage and one for Prod. Automatically detecting if page was delivered by Stage or Prod Server and based on that initializing desired pixel. And Features like delaying the calls to 'PageView' and add Custom Events, Video Tracking, Lead Tracking etc.

I made minor changes to how the code for Facebook pixel gets called and now the tracking does NOT work for Safari and Firefox. The same code still works for Chrome.

What am I doing wrong in breaking out the Pixel code here:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

if(servedByProd()){
  fbq('init', '<Prod-Pixel-Id>');
  console.log("Initializing FB Pixel for Prod server.");
} else {
  fbq('init', '<Stage-Pixel-Id>');
  console.log("Initializing FB Pixel for Stage server.");
}

function reportPageViewToFB(delayInMs){

  if(typeof delayInMs !== 'undefined'){

     setTimeout( function(){ 
                 fbq('track', 'PageView');    
                 console.log("PageView reported to FB after delay (ms) " + delayInMs);
                 }, delayInMs );
  } else {
     fbq('track', 'PageView');
  }
}
```

I make a call to reportPageViewToFB(5000) in onload() method and I see it being fired after 5 seconds elapse in all browsers - including Safari and Firefox. But under Facebook Pixel's test events, I do not see it coming in when attempted from Safari or Firefox, it works no problem with Chrome.

All other events that I fire also fail for Safari and Firefox. Like Video Progress or Lead, etc.

Comment: [It's a feature, not a bug.](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2019/06/04/firefox-now-available-with-enhanced-tracking-protection-by-default/)

Comment: @AuxTaco - Thanks.  You're probably right. I was almost certain that I was able to see events from Safari on Facebook Pixel. But now I can't seem to find any method where it worked.